# Does MIT/GNU Scheme have a C FFI?

Tags: ffi, mit-scheme

I've checked its manuals and haven't found much to say that it does, but neither have I found anything to the contrary.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ffi/

Comment: Is there any reason why this isn't accessible from the main MIT/GNU Scheme page?

Answer (score 1):

[MIT/GNU Scheme - Foreign function interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Foreign-function-interface.html#Foreign-function-interface)

> **18.2 Foreign Function Interface**
>
> The Win32 foreign function interface (FFI) is a primitive and fairly
>   simple system for calling procedures written in C in a dynamically
>   linked library (DLL). Both user's procedures from a custom DLL and
>   system procedures (e.g. MessageBox) are called using the same
>   mechanism.
>
> **Warning**: The FFI as it stands has several flaws which make it
>   difficult to use reliably. It is expected that both the interface to
>   and the mechanisms used by the FFI will be changed in the future. We
>   provide it, and this documentation, only to give people an early start
>   in accessing some of the features of Win32 from Scheme. Should you use
>   it in an experiment we welcome any feedback.
>
> The FFI is designed for calling C procedures that use C data types
>   rather than Scheme data objects. Thus it is not possible to write and
>   call a C procedure that returns, for example, a Scheme list. The
>   object returned will always be an integer (which may represent the
>   address of a C data structure).
>
> **Warning**: It is extremely dangerous to try to pass Scheme callback
>   procedures to C procedures. It is only possible by passing integer
>   `handles' rather than the actual procedures, and even so, if a garbage
>   collection occurs during the execution of the callback procedure
>   objects in Scheme's heap will have moved. Thus in a foreign procedure
>   that has a callback and a string, after calling the callback the
>   string value may no longer be valid. Playing this game requires a
>   profound knowledge of the implementation.
>
> The interface to the FFI has two main components: a language for
>   declaring the types of values passed to and returned from the foreign
>   procedures and a form for declaring foreign procedures.

The reference to Win32 in this documentation, I believe refers to calling Windows NT/3.1 functions from GNU/Linux. At least the **18.2 Foreign Function Interface** section is a subsection of the **18 Win32 Package Reference** section.

Comment: What about GNU/Linux? That's why I'm asking, really.

Comment: I think I misread what they refer to as Win32 here. It seems to be a Win32 package that enables calling Windows NT/ 3.1 functions. So I think they refer to calling these functions from GNU/Linux.